# apex_application.g_notification

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to do a notification message when doing a process on submit but is not working

```
DECLARE

l_sendto NUMBER := :P22_SEND_TO;
l_user_groups NUMBER := :P22_USER_GROUP;
l_media NUMBER := :P22_MEDIA;
l_usersessionid NUMBER := :APP_SESSION;
SINGLE_USER CONSTANT number :=0;
l_aux NUMBER;

e EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
--verify if user 
select userid into l_aux FROM SURV_TEMP_SENDTO WHERE userid = l_user_groups and usersessionid= l_usersessionid and rownum =1;

IF l_aux > 0 THEN
  RAISE e;
ELSE     
  IF l_sendto = SINGLE_USER THEN
     --if selected all types of medias of one user    
        INSERT INTO SURV_TEMP_SENDTO (userid, mediatypeid, usersessionid)
                (SELECT zm.userid, zm.mediatypeid, l_usersessionid  
                  FROM z.media zm, Z.media_type zmt 
                  WHERE zmt.mediatypeid = zm.mediatypeid 
                  AND zm.userid = l_user_groups);
    apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'Inserting OK';
END IF;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN e THEN
    apex_application.g_global_notification:= 'Error inserting values';
    --apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'Error inserting values';
END;
```

In the raise EXCEPTION it doesn't show any msg but if he enters the ELSE it writes the success msg.

Anyone know why it doesn't work in EXCEPTION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ELSE you are using `g_print_success_message`.  That will work in the EXCEPTION section too.  When I tried it, `g_global_notification` didn't work in either main body or exception section, but only appeared if an exception was raised and not handled - I don't know why though.

Comment: Ok, so the `g_global_notification` and `g_notification` don't work like `g_print_success_message` ?

Comment: It appears not.  I find that g_global_notification only works when an exception is actually raised or re-raised; when Apex thinks the process has succeeded it gets overwritten with the application's default global notification message.

Comment: Tanks for helping me i have to see what i can do with success_message